Qt не размещается окно
Начал разбирать тему по изменинию размеров и положению окон . Возникла проблема что следующий код:
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QScreen>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     QApplication a(argc, argv);
     QWidget w;
     w.setWindowTitle("Hello");

     w.setGeometry(1000, 1000, 350, 70);
     qDebug() << w.geometry();

     w.show();
     return a.exec();
}

Не изменяет положени окнана экране (указывал разные значение для setGeometry())
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Qt 6.4

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/application-windows.html#wayland-peculiarities

Это точно не setGeometry(). Дальше все зависит от оконного менеджера. На вейланде вообще невозможно, На X11 гарантированно работает только через --geometry в командной строке, в противном случае нужно создавать окно без рамки. Если коротко- рамка окна на линухе управляется совсем другой программой )
